# Saving updated values of a dojo data grid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Can anyone tell me how to connect my dojo datagrid to "onApplyCellEdit" event and how to update the dojo store with the updated values in the grid. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if youre using a store which implements dojo.data.api.Write (like ItemFileWriteStore or such), then your store will handle this by default, once it is connected to a datagrid.

When youre done editing (or do it on cell.onblur or like) check if any changes was made to store by calling `store.isDirty()`. If it returns true, either a new, modified or deleted item is not in sync with server.

To sync, look into the api.Write and see that for every store there is a call `.save()` - which ofc you must implement (unless you leverage REST with PUT/DELETE/POST pattern)